# Is it possible to access any databases other than MySQL using phpmyadmin?

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I heard that phpmyadmin is a GUI used to access MySQL DB. I wish to know whether any other databases are compatible to work with phpmyadmin.

Comment: Please put a little effort to research the question for yourself.  Right from http://www.phpmyadmin.net/ *phpMyAdmin supports a wide range of operations on MySQL, MariaDB and Drizzle*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [phpMyAdmin Docs](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/faq.html#faq1-17), the following databases are supported:

> Since phpMyAdmin 3.0.x, only MySQL 5.0.1 and newer are supported. For older MySQL versions, you need to use the latest 2.x branch.
>
> [ ... ]
>
> MariaDB is also supported (versions 5.1 and 5.2 were tested)
>
> [...]
>
> Changed in version 3.5: Since phpMyAdmin 3.5 Drizzle is supported.